# How do i make my grass particles collide with other objects or have them not appear under where other objects are?

Tags: particles, collision

Sorry I'm a big blender noob. I have these flower objects, and i made a hair particles for the chunky grass around them. I want the grass to either avoid them OR not be in the areas where the flower objects are. I have collision modifiers on these flowers, what else do I need to do? Also it would be good if there was a setting so that the particles didn't overlap?

If I didn't want the grass to appear where the flowers are and only around them, is this possible? I'll also eventually have the grass be affected by a wind force field, but this hasn't been done yet.

I will share screenshots of my settings but I'm not sure which would be useful to share. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I've found that if i subdivide my plane and weight paint it, and then use that vertex group on the density of the particles and invert it, i can paint the areas I don't want the grass to show up. (beneath the flowers) but i still need to make the grass collide with the flowers. Really scratching my head!